# Powershell Silent Install in Nano Server with Docker

Tags: powershell, docker, start-process, nano-server

My docker file gets a Nano Server container and it adds Java automatically.

```
# Get nano server
FROM microsoft/nanoserver

# Download file and set in docker container
ADD http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=225355_090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135 \ 
    'C:\\java\jre-8u151-windows-x64.exe'

# Silent install and delete install file
RUN powershell Start-Process -filepath C:\java\jre-8u151-windows-x64.exe -ArgumentList '/s,INSTALLDIR=c:\Java\jre1.8.0_151' -Passthru -Wait; \
    Remove-Item C:\\java\jre-8u151-windows-x64.exe -Force

CMD powershell
```

The process works correctly but in Nano Server it does not install anything without showing any error. However, with Core Server it does install it.

The result of the silent installation is:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
              3      476       1464               596   1 jre-8u151-windows-x64
```

But then, when I check if it is installed with `dir` command, I see the following result:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       12/21/2017  11:04 AM                Program Files
d-----        7/16/2016   2:09 PM                Program Files (x86)
d-r---        11/3/2017   8:44 PM                Users
d-----       12/21/2017  11:05 AM                Windows
-a----        7/24/2017   6:05 PM       65365056 jre-8u151-windows-x64.exe
-a----       11/20/2016  12:32 PM           1894 License.txt
```

How could I make this process work correctly or what alternative can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows nano server does not support MSI based installation. It supports WSA. Please refer to:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nanoserver/2015/11/18/installing-windows-server-apps-on-nano-server/