# How to build Docker images with node installed

Tags: node.js, docker

As of .netcore 2.1, node is not installed on the .net-images (**windows** images) .

How would you install node on your docker images? Here are some links, that doesnt seem to work for me, mostly because I get an error when running powershell. I only want to download official (from ms directly) images

https://github.com/a11smiles/docker-nano-nodejs/blob/master/Dockerfile

[Can't install node in docker image microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk for windows architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980581/cant-install-node-in-docker-image-microsoft-dotnet2-1-sdk-for-windows-architec)

Comment: why not use the _official_ node.js docker image?

Comment: All I could find in that department was this https://hub.docker.com/_/node/ (only linux)

Comment: yes it's a Linux based image as most Docker image are. Since your container is in Node.js, why would you need other than that?

Comment: Corporate policy

Comment: oh algright. Got you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [microsoft/aspnetcore-build](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore-build/) docker image, since it comes with **Node.js**. It's from **Microsoft** and has:

- **Node.js**
- NET Core SDK
- Bower
- Gulp

Comment: Wow, thanks!.. .how did I miss that. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Oh wait. I take that back... Ive been that path before. the  microsoft/aspnetcore-build  does not support .net core 2.1+.. back to the drawing board

Comment: can you update your question so it includes __all the details__ you need? Like .net core 2.1+, microsoft image with node.js. Maybe other requirements? Thanks